# Dirac delta function and well behaved function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

whether dirac delta function a well behaved function? Can u please explain the properties of a   well behaved function..?

Comment: Multi-duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is NOT a function, because it does not have the property that it can be given a value  at every point of its "domain".

It is a completely different entity called a [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29).